# Custom Google search bar results not clickable

Tags: html

I have a personal new tab start page with a search bar that opens a google search in a new tab

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search?q="  target="_blank" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="q" >
 <input type="submit" value="Go">
 <button type="reset" value="reset">X</button>
</form>
```

The links on the Google result page do not open, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your code is working fine and also opening the google links.what do you want to do ?

Comment: Weird, could it be a problem with opening it from codepen?

Comment: may be. i tried your code and from google links are opening

Comment: try in your local system

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to figure out some alternative, I just ran it off of codepen for the convenience

Comment: pleasure. okay sure

Comment: The problem might be Codepen. As stated before, your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zprhobnq/

Comment: I tried running the fiddle you posted and am having the same results of not being able to click the results, scratching my head